# Returning error number as string when only Int32Ptr is accepted in Matlab

Tags: c++, c, matlab, dll

I'm new to using dll files in Matlab and am having some trouble returning the errorNumber. The documentation for the dll is specific to C and suggests using the following to achieve what I want to:

```
#include “PiUsb.h”

void * pUsb1;
int ErrorNumber;
int MotorSerialNumber = 10; // Serial number from Motor

pUsb1 = piConnectMotor(&ErrorNumber,MotorSerialNum);
if (ErrorNumber == PI_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND)
AfxMessageBox( "Unable to find Motor..." );
else
AfxMessageBox( "Motor Connected." );
```

However, I want to be able to do this in Matlab.

I've succesffully loaded the dll into Matlab with:

```
fullpathToPiUSBHeader = [pwd filesep 'picardStage' filesep 'PiUsb.h']
fullpathToPiUSBDll = [pwd filesep 'picardStage' filesep 'PiUsb.dll']
fullpathToPiUSBHeader = [pwd filesep 'picardStage' filesep 'PiUsb.h']

if not(libisloaded(fullpathToPiUSBHeader))
  loadlibrary(fullpathToPiUSBDll,fullpathToPiUSBHeader)
end

libfunctions('PiUsb','-full')
```

And I'm returned the full list of functions, in particular this function:

```
[lib.pointer, int32Ptr] = piConnectMotor(int32Ptr, int32)
```

However, when I try to implement it, I'm expecting a string back, which means I need to initialise errorNumber as a string. However, the function will only accept Int32Ptr as the data type.

This is what I've got so far:

```
xMotorSerialNumber = 12345;
errorNumber = libpointer('int32Ptr',{'PI_NO_ERROR','PI_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND'});
[xMotor, errorNumber] = calllib('PiUsb','piConnectMotor',errorNumber,xMotorSerialNumber)
```

However I receive the following error message back:

```
Array must be numeric or logical or a pointer to one
```

Which I assume is due to the errorNumber values being strings instead of integers, however when I use:

```
errorNumber = libpointer('int32Ptr',[0]);
```

The errorNumber returned is always '1', irrespective of whether the device is connected or not.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look here:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lib.pointer-class.html

Instead:

```
errorNumber = libpointer('int32Ptr',[0]);
```

Try:

```
errorNumber = libpointer('int32Ptr',0);
```

Remember that ErrorNumber is an int, then you need to pass to the function a pointer to an integer.

Finally, you can try:

```
get(errorNumber)
```

After calling the function, to see the value of errorNumber.

And instead:

```
[xMotor, errorNumber] = calllib('PiUsb','piConnectMotor',errorNumber,xMotorSerialNumber)
```

Try:

```
calllib('PiUsb','piConnectMotor',errorNumber,xMotorSerialNumber)
```

Comment: Thanks! However, when I use `get(errorNumber)`, I'm still returned the value of 1, instead of a string of `'PI_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND'`. Also, when I try and use `xMotor = libpointer;` and then `get(xMotor)`, I consistently get the error The datatype and size of the value must be defined before the value can be retrieved even though it has been defined as void.

Comment: @GeeDeeJay look here: https://valelab.ucsf.edu/svn/3rdpartypublic/Picard/20140430/4D-Stage%20DLL%20and%20Docs/PiUsb.h 1 means PI_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: Thank you so much!